# Returning File in a site with Authentication

Tags: file, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/471384

I'm using Orchard CMS 1.7 and we locked the entire site from anonymous users (admin -> users -> roles -> untick site front-end). Now, each page or file requires folks to be authenticated before getting access to them.

Now, we're trying to provide the option of having some files available for download, depending on a field from a specific Content Type.

**The ISSUE**

When I download the file while I am authenticated, I get the it without issues. If I'm anonymous, I get the file (correct filename and type) but it has no contents and size (0 bytes). I'm pretty sure this is an auth issue since it all works well when I enable anonymous access to site front end.

This is the actual code of returning the file (redirectLink is the filepath):

```
                    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                    {
                        FileName = fileName,
                        Inline = false
                    };

                    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
                    return File(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(redirectLink), mimeType);
```

Here is my complete code (Controller Action):

```
        [AlwaysAccessible]
        public ActionResult Download(int resourceId)
        {
            //set default unsecure value to false
            bool isUnsecured = false;

            var resourceItem = ContentManager.Get(resourceId);
            if (resourceItem == null || resourceItem.ContentType != "Resource")
            {
                // TODO: log that ID not found??
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            var resourcePart = resourceItem.Parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.PartDefinition.Name == resourceItem.ContentType);

            //retrieve unsecure boolean
            if (resourcePart != null)
            {
                var unsecuredField = resourcePart.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Unsecured");
                if (unsecuredField != null)
                {
                    isUnsecured = unsecuredField.Storage.Get<bool>();
                }
            }

            //check if unsecured resource / allow anonymous downloads
            //see Orchard.Security.SecurityFilter - I'm not sure where this is actually used in Orchard though...
            if (!isUnsecured && !Services.Authorizer.Authorize(StandardPermissions.AccessFrontEnd, T("Unauthenticated")))
            {
                return new HttpUnauthorizedResult(); 
            }                                     

            if (resourcePart != null)
            {
                // TODO: Potential concurrency issues?
                var downloadCountPart = resourcePart.As<DownloadCountPart>();
                if (downloadCountPart != null)
                {
                    downloadCountPart.Total++;
                    ContentManager.Publish(resourceItem);
                }

                // Do the redirection/serving of item!
                // Prioritize link field over resource field, according to the UI
                var linkedField = resourcePart.Fields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "LinkedFile");
                if (linkedField != null)
                {
                    var redirectLink = linkedField.Storage.Get<string>();
                    if (redirectLink != null)
                    {
                        return Redirect(redirectLink);
                    }
                }

                var resourceField = resourcePart.Fields.First(f => f.Name == "ResourceFile");
                if (resourceField != null)
                {
                    var resourceMPF = (resourceField as MediaLibraryPickerField);     

                    if (resourceMPF != null && resourceMPF.MediaParts != null && resourceMPF.MediaParts.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        var fileName = resourceMPF.MediaParts.First().FileName;
                        var mimeType = resourceMPF.MediaParts.First().MimeType;
                        var redirectLink = resourceMPF.MediaParts.First().MediaUrl;       //to check: first? when are there multiple?
                        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(redirectLink))
                        {

                            var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
                            {
                                FileName = fileName,
                                Inline = false
                            };

                            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
                            return File(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(redirectLink), mimeType);
                        }

                    }                   
                }
            }

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
```

Which leads me to these questions:

1. Event with return File, it still takes into account the current user
   and whether that person is authenticated?
2. Can I use impersonation to bypass this issue?

Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the empty file is because of a bug in the Output Cache module that is only active for anonymous users. This bug is fixed in Orchard 1.7.2, so an upgrade will help.

Also since mainly authenticated users use your site and thus you don't really make use of output caching as a temporal workaround you could just disable the module until you upgrade (what I'd advice, since such anonymous file downloads can be cached for better performance).

Comment: Worked perfectly, although it didn't reflect instantly. I went on to delete cache.dat and other stuff in App_Data just be sure. Thanks!